# How to reshape each 5 consecutive values to one row and append datetime?

Tags: r, date, matrix

I have a sensor that is recording some values every second where the series of 5 values is one measurement.

This is the example data:

```
  sensor<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1.1,2.1,3.2,4.2,5.1,1.2,2.2,3.1,4.3,5.4,1.1,2.22,3.3,4.9,5.55)
  clock<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-05-05 13:10:00"),by="1 sec")
  time<-clock[1:length(sensor)]
  orig<-data.frame(sensor,time)
  orig

     sensor          time
1    1.00 2010-03-01 13:02:00
2    2.00 2010-03-01 13:02:01
3    3.00 2010-03-01 13:02:02
4    4.00 2010-03-01 13:02:03
5    5.00 2010-03-01 13:02:04
6    1.10 2010-03-01 13:02:05
7    2.10 2010-03-01 13:02:06
8    3.20 2010-03-01 13:02:07
```

What I want to do is to reshape the data so that every measurement is in a separeted row.

where the expected output looks like this:

```
1  1.0 2.00  3.0  4.0 5.00 13:02:05
2  1.1 2.10  3.2  4.2 5.10 13:02:10
3  1.2 2.20  3.1  4.3 5.40 13:02:15
4  1.1 2.22  3.3  4.9 5.55 13:02:20
```

When I try to put the data in the matrix form:

```
clock2<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-05-05 13:10:00"),by="5 sec")
tx<-t(matrix(sensor,5,4))
newd<-cbind(tx,clock2[1:nrow(tx)])
newd


     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]       [,6]
[1,]  1.0 2.00  3.0  4.0 5.00 1267444920
[2,]  1.1 2.10  3.2  4.2 5.10 1267444920
[3,]  1.2 2.20  3.1  4.3 5.40 1267444920
[4,]  1.1 2.22  3.3  4.9 5.55 1267444920
```

I'm looking for suggestions how to solve this. Maybe there is a better solution than using matrix

Comment: `matrix` can hold only a single class so it coerces to a single class.  Use `data.frame` or `list`

Comment: using newd<-data.frame(tx,clock2[1:row(bb)]) is not working eather

Comment: Please have the question title reflect the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has requested to reshape the data so that 5 consecutive sensor values which make up one measurement appear in a row. In addition, the time of the end of measurement period is to be appended.

As already pointed out [in akrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705996/adding-a-datetimet-into-the-matrix#comment84410349_48705996), a `matrix` does not work here because a `matrix` can only hold a single class. So, we need to use a `data.frame` object which can hold the 5 numeric columns and one column of class `POSIXct`.

For reshaping, the `dcast()` function is used:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(orig)[, rn := .I - 1L], 
      (time[5L * rn %/% 5L + 1L] + 5) ~ paste0("V", rn %% 5L + 1L), 
      value.var = "sensor")
```

> ```
>                   time  V1  V2  V3   V4   V5
> 1: 2010-03-01 13:02:05 1.0 2.00 3.0 4.0 5.00
> 2: 2010-03-01 13:02:10 1.1 2.10 3.2 4.2 5.10
> 3: 2010-03-01 13:02:15 1.2 2.20 3.1 4.3 5.40
> 4: 2010-03-01 13:02:20 1.1 2.22 3.3 4.9 5.55
> ```

Alternatively, `floor_date()` from the `lubridate` package can be used to avoid the index arithmetic:

```
dcast(setDT(orig)[, rn := .I - 1L], 
      lubridate::floor_date(time + 5, unit = " 5 second") ~ paste0("V", rn %% 5L + 1L), 
      value.var = "sensor")
```

#### Data

```
sensor <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.2, 5.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 4.3, 5.4, 1.1, 2.22, 3.3, 4.9, 5.55)
time <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02:00"), length.out = length(sensor), by = "1 sec")
orig <- data.frame(sensor, time)
```